# How to create button to go to certain sheet in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I want to create a script for a button in google sheets so that when I press it, it will take me to a specific tab within that workbook

i.e. the first tab will be a contents page with buttons to take me to certain tab in that google sheet

Please bear in mind I do not know how to write scripts but can create buttons

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple script and assign it to a button if this works for you.

```
function goToSheet() {

var name = "Sheet1"; //change the string inside the quotation marks to set the sheet name
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetname = sheets.getSheetByName(name);
sheets.setActiveSheet(sheetname);

}
```

**NOTE:**

You would need to manually indicate the name of the sheet on the `name` variable, and it does not automatically update when you renamed a specific tab on your sheet.

Comment: Hi, when you say "indicate the name of the sheet on the name variable" do I replace the name with the sheet I want it to go to? 
i.e. 

function goToSheet() {

var name = "Contents"; //change this code to set the sheet name
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetname = sheets.getSheetByName(name);
sheets.setActiveSheet(sheetname);

Comment: Yes that is correct, to be more specific, you indicate there the name of the Tab you would want it to go to @apacheuk

Comment: Ok Thanks. Did that. New problem, when I assign the script to the button I get:    There was a problem
Script function Contents_Page could not be found

Comment: Would it be alright if you can share your sheet so that we can double check? @apacheuk